# extract data from variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

I have a variable in ruby on rails which contains this value  **8,375 TND**

```
_result = _orig_account.formatted_balance(_currency)
```

I want if it is possible to eliminate **TND** and then **multiply the rest  by 1000**    in order to have as a result **8375**

can sameone help me to solve this problem

I try with this code :

```
I try with : _tes = _orig_account.formatted_balance().tr(',', '.').to_f
         _te = _tes * 1000
```

and I have as a result :  **8375.0**

but as I said I want juste **8375**

Comment: Show us what you've tried? And, honestly, if you can't figure that out, then you really need to be learning to program in Ruby, and leave Rails for later. This is a pretty basic task in any language. A clue for you is to look into using String's [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) and [`to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) methods.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Just use this `'8,375 TND'.tr(',', '').to_i`

Comment: What will happen if the number he needs to multiply by 1000 doesn't have a `,`, say, `1`.

Comment: exactly the same. No side effects were encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple manipulation:

```
'8,375 TND'.tr(',', '.').to_f
=> 8.375
```

Multiply that by 1000.

Comment: Yeah it was stupid, I just improved your solution. I'm still new here, maybe it was better to comment on your answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I use your code I have : 8375.0

Comment: That's because you are multiplying a floating point number by an integer. TND is specified using `,` as the decimal point so you have to use a float to represent it simply. (It's not really as simple as that, but that's a separate subject.) If you want to drop the floating point use `to_i` after the multiplication.